# Filter on keyof type parameter in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

No need to know React, just some background: in my use case, I want to amplify user specified React.ComponentClass with my custom Higher Order Component. In order to do so, I want user to also send me list of names of the particular props my Higher Order Component will inject. That would be done like this:

```
function listToComponentProps<TComponentProps, TKey = keyof TComponentProps>(props: Array<TKey>) {
  // Logic here, not important for the example
}
interface TestProps {a: number, b: Function, c: () => number}
listToComponentProps<TestProps>(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

The `keyof` keyword handles the constraint for me.
Example inputs for `listToComponentProps<TestProps>` would be

- valid:  `['b']`, `['b', 'c']`, `['c']`
- invalid

  - `['a']`, `['a', 'b']`, `['a', 'b', 'c']` (a is number, not a function)
  - `['d']`, `['d', 'c']` (d is not part of the interface `TestProps`

The problem is, I want to restrict the `props` parameter not only to be key of `TComponentProps`, but also such key that the  corresponding type in `TComponentProps` is `Function` (so that `'a'` would be an invalid option detected by typescript compiler). How can one achieve such task?

Comment: You should be aware that the user can just do `listToComponentProps<TestProps, "a" | "b" | "c" | "d">(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])` with this setup. Neither of `TComponentProps` and `TKey` are actually restricting each other here.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. However, user of the Higher Order Component will not have a direct access to the function, listToComponentProps will be only an internal function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
const listToComponentProps = <
  TComponent extends {[P in TKey]: Function },
  TKey extends string = keyof TComponent>
  (props: TKey[]) => { /* ... */ };

interface TestProps {a: number, b: Function, c: () => number}
const result = listToComponentProps<TestProps>(['a', 'b', 'c']) // Type error
```

This results in the type error:

```
Type 'TestProps' does not satisfy the constraint '{ a: Function; b: Function; c: Function; }'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
```

---

Unfortunately this business of having a default parameter ends up constraining our `TComponent` to have only `Function` properties. When you genuinely want to pass something like `listToComponentProps<TestProps>(['b', 'c'])`, which should be valid, you will need to explicitly fill in the second type parameter, i.e. `listToComponentProps<TestProps, 'b' | 'c'>(['b', 'c'])`.

What you *really* want is not to have a default parameter for `TKey`, but rather for generic inference to be granular: in a type parameter list, all parameters that *can* be inferred (e.g. `TKey`, which can be inferred from the passed array) *should* be inferred, even if some (in this case, `TComponent`) have to be specified manually. TypeScript doesn't work this way today, so we're SOL.

There's a bunch of open issues on the TypeScript issue tracker about this, you could go find them and kick up a stink.

---

If good inference is more important to you than strictly preserving runtime characteristics, you could add a dummy argument to dissociate inference for the two type parameters:

```
const listToComponentProps =
    <TKey extends string>
    (props: TKey[]) =>
    <TComponent extends {[P in TKey]: Function }>
    () => { /* ... */ };

interface TestProps { a: number, b: Function, c: () => number }

const result = listToComponentProps(['a', 'b', 'c'])<TestProps>() // Type error
const result2 = listToComponentProps(['b', 'c'])<TestProps>() // OK
```

Comment: almost there, I realize the question was not written precisely, I also need it to accept only part of the interface, such as ['b', 'c']. I have updated the question.

Comment: @netchkin I understand, I've expanded the answer.

Comment: Wow! Just... Wow! Thanks a bunch. Indeed, at this time, I value inference more, so I'll use that.

Comment: @netchkin I just realized the dummy argument doesn't necessarily need to be a curried argument. At the expense of a little syntactic awkwardness, you could do `<TKey extends string, TComponent extends ...>(props: TKey[], dummy?: TComponent) => ...`, then `listToComponentProps(['b', 'c'], undefined as TestProps)`. This eliminates the runtime impact.

Comment: pretty cool, even though a syntatic error is attached to `TComponent` instead of `props`.

Comment: @AndréWerlang I'm not seeing any syntactic errors. When you provide the wrong type, the only thing I see is a type error.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Probably the arguments will be wrong, not the type. In this case, the type will be underlined in the IDE, instead of the wrong arguments.

Comment: @AndréWerlang There is a difference between syntactic and type errors. What you are seeing is likely not a syntax error. If you have managed to reproduce a syntactic error, please post a reproducible example in the TypeScript playground.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin you're right. a type error is not a syntactic error. But that's not the point. Will not spend time on that. In case my previous comment didn't make it clear, let me rephrase: *pretty cool, even though a type error is attached to `TComponent` instead of `props`*